# Open subset of the large plane which isn't formed from Borel sets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

*Some background.* I was looking for a product of two Borel $σ$-algebras which is not Borel. I know that the two topological spaces mustn't be second-countable. I then googled an example of such a space and found the long line on Wikipedia.

*Now the problem.* The *large plane* is the topological product of two long lines. The disjoint union of uncountably many unit squares, let's say
$$A:=\bigcup_{α∈ω_1} \bigl] (α,0),(α,1) \bigr[^2,$$
seems (until I'm proved wrong...) a reasonable bet for an open set which is not in the product of the Borel $σ$-algebra of the long line with itself. However, I'm still not able to prove it. <strike>Should I give up?</strike> Is my conjecture true?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if the product of two long lines works, but here is a somewhat simpler and more straightforward counterexample.

Let $X$ be *any* set whose cardinality is greater than that of the continuum (for example, the power set of $\mathbb R$). Endow it with the discrete topology. Let $D\equiv\{(x,x)\mid x\in X\}$ be the diagonal of $X\times X$. Then, $D$ is clopen (as is *any* subset of $X\times X$) in the product topology, so it lies in $\mathscr B_{X\times X}$ (which is, of course, the discrete $\sigma$-algebra on $X\times X$).

However, $D\notin\mathscr B_X\otimes\mathscr B_X$. If $D$ were in the product of the Borel $\sigma$-algebras, then there would exist a $\sigma$-subalgebra $\mathscr M\subseteq\mathscr B_X\otimes\mathscr B_X$ that is generated by a countable class of measurable rectangles and $D\in\mathscr M$. It follows that there exists a countably generated $\sigma$-subalgebra $\mathscr N\subseteq\mathscr B_X$ with $D\in\mathscr N\otimes\mathscr N$. Then, since $\{x\}$ is a coordinate projection of $D$ for every $x\in X$, one would have that $\{x\}\in\mathscr N$. This is impossible, given that $\mathscr N$ is countably generated, so that its cardinality cannot be greater than that of $\mathbb R$.

For more details, see [Folland (1999)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160), in particular: Exercise 7.29 (page 231), Exercise 1.5 (page 24), and Proposition 1.23 (page 40).